# How to trigger ServiceNow workflow from ui action?

Tags: button, triggers, workflow, action, servicenow

I am getting started with workflows in ServiceNow. I can see that the trigger for at workflow is based on conditions. But can a workflow be triggered by some sort of user action, i.e. a UI Action/button or through a script?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a `Workflow` object accessible server side that you can use to start a workflow that's [documented here](http://wiki.servicenow.com/index.php?title=Workflow_Script#startFlow.28workflowId.2C_current.2C_operation.2C_vars.29).

Here's an example from that wiki article:

```
// where current is a task record with a workflow context
var w = new Workflow();
var context = w.startFlow(id, current, current.operation(), vars);
```

- `current`: A GlideRecord that's been `next()`'ed to the record against which you're running the workflow
- `id`: The sys_id of the `wf_workflow` you want to run (NOTE: This is NOT the workflow **version**, the `startFlow` method handles determining which version is **published** and executes against it.
- `vars`: The input variables that your target workflow accepts. This should be a JavaScript associative array e.g.:
  `var vars = {variable1: "value1", variable2: "value2"};`

Comment: That link appears to be dead now. Here's the link to the docs for Workflow as of Kingston: https://docs.servicenow.com/bundle/kingston-application-development/page/app-store/dev_portal/API_reference/Workflow/concept/c_Workflow_api.html#ariaid-title19