# Can I start a Service Now workflow via an external SOAP call?

Tags: soap, workflow, servicenow

I would like to make a call into the ServiceNow SOAP webservice to start an instance of a specific web service.

I can find the WSDL for functions like incident.do but seem to be missing the step needed to find the proper table/endpoint for workflows to start.

Comment: You'd probably need to setup a custom scripted web service on the ServiceNow instance. From there, you can kick off a workflow from script using my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34005305/25962

Comment: @Joey So you cannot make a SOAP call, to write an entry to any table, and provide the <vars> node data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to start a Workflow via SOAP I think the only way to do this is to create a [Scripted Web-Service](http://wiki.servicenow.com/index.php?title=Scripted_Web_Services) or a [Custom Processor](http://wiki.servicenow.com/index.php?title=Tutorial_4_Creating_a_Custom_Processor).

In there you will have to define a script which starts your Workflow.

```
var w = new Workflow();
var context = w.startFlow(id, current, current.operation(), getVars());
```

In [this](http://wiki.servicenow.com/index.php?title=Workflow_Script) wiki article you can find API Methods for Workflows.

Answer (score 2):

The tricky bit is getting the variables into the Workflow.
While this sounds easy, in fact it isn't.

If your workflow runs on the table sc_req_item (which is likely if you are dealing with Request Fulfillment), you first need to set the Property (sys_properties) *glide.workflow.enable_input_variables* to true, because otherwise, you will not be able to add normal Input variables to your workflow.

Then, add the Input variables to the workflow. Note that you have some nifty datatypes [available there](https://docs.servicenow.com/bundle/helsinki-platform-administration/page/administer/reference-pages/reference/r_FieldTypes.html). Note for example the "Data Structure" type.
All Input variables are treated like custome columns (in fact they are columns of a workflw-specific table). That is why the names start with *u_*.

Lets say, you define an input variable called *u_dynamic_vars* (Datatype "Data Structure").

Here is how to call the workflow:

```
var wf_name = "Name of your workflow";

// Instantiate JSON machinery
var parser = new JSON();

//Declare an instance  of workflow.js 
var wf  = new Workflow ();
//Get the workflow id 
var  wfId  = wf.getWorkflowFromName (wf_name) ;

//Start workflow, passing along object containing name/value pairs mapping to inputs expected by the workflow 
var vars  = { } ;

// Prepare the JSON Datastructure
var obj ={"name":"George",
      "lastname":"Washington"};

// Encode the data
vars.u_dynamic_vars = parser.encode(obj);
vars.u_new_email = "inject@new.com";


// Get a specific RITM
var gr = GlideRecord("sc_req_item");
gr.get("18d8e9740f4013002f504c6be1050e48");
gs.print(gr.number);

// Start the Workflow with a "current" record
wf.startFlow(wfId , gr , "update" , vars ) ;

// You may also pass null, then current is null.
wf.startFlow(wfId , null , "update" , vars ) ;
```

In the workflow, you then unpack the data like so:

```
// Let's unpack it. For some reason, intantiating the parse won't work here...
payload = JSON.parse(workflow.variables.u_dynamic_vars);
gs.print("payload.first_name:" + payload.name);
```

Also note that a workflow does not necessarily need to run on a table.
To achieve this, choose "global" as table name when defining the workflow.